# No modules name Items in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

When i run My spider in scrapy  it show no modules name items

In Items file i have defined only two items and i need to  make csv for that items and in spider file iam importing that file and in console importing error is shown below

Here is code of items file  :

```
import scrapy

class OddsItem(scrapy.Item):
    Title = scrapy.Field()
    Date = scrapy.Field()
```

Here is code of spider:

```
import scrapy
import time
from odds.items import OddsItem
from selenium import webdriver


class OddsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "odds"
  ...... other code ....
```

Error in console :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 142, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 209, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 115, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 296, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 30, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 21, in __init__
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/yohack/scraping_scrapy/odds/odds/odds/spiders/odds.py", line 3, in <module>
    from odds.items import OddsItem
ImportError: No module named items
```

Comment: What does your project file structure look like?  It's probably that you've got `items.py` in the wrong place (even more likely given that horrible path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy generates the following directory structure by default

```
odds/
|
|---scrapy.cfg            # deploy configuration file
|
`---odds/             # project's Python module, you'll import your code from here
    |
    |---__init__.py
    |
    |---items.py          # project items file
    |
    |---pipelines.py      # project pipelines file
    |
    |---settings.py       # project settings file
    |
    `---spiders/          # a directory where you'll later put your spiders
        |
        |---__init__.py
        |
        `---odds.py
```

.

```
from odds.items import OddsItem
```

Looks for items.py in the `odds` directory containing `__init__`.py and spiders directory by default. Check if you have this structure right. Also make sure you have `__init__`.py file in that folder it tells python to look for sub modules in that directory.